# How to activate a conda environment from spyder

Tags: bash, conda, spyder

I installed a Conda environment in a Ubuntu terminal to do some bioinformatic process.
At the begining I was working in the Ubuntu terminal, now i want to improve the process combining bash and python usind Spyder 4.2.5 IDE, so i would like to activate my environment but I got a wrong.

I try to activate with the next comand:
`Conda activate MY-ENV`

I got the next message:

````
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.```


I tried to use "$ conda init <SHELL_NAME>" but i got the same result.
````